# Random walks in $\mathbb{Z}^2$

Tags: probability-theory, statistics

Consider a random walk on the integer lattice in the plane. If a “particle” making a random
walk arrives at a lattice point $p = (k_1,k_2)$ at the time $t$, then one of the four neighbors
$(k_1±1, k_2 )$, $(k_1 , k_2 ± 1)$ of p is selected with equal probability $\frac{1}{4}$ . The particle moves to that neighbor at time $t + 1$.
Let $D$ be a region in the plane (a square or a half plane for example), and let $B$ denote its boundary. Let $p$ be a point of $D$, and let $b$ be a boundary point. We’ll denote by $P_p(b)$ the probability that a random walk starting at $p$ exits at $b$, i.e., that $b$ is the first boundary point that is reached.

I was wondering if someone could help me answer some questions if the region in the plane that we are considering is a rectangle.

1) What is the probability that a particle starting at $p$ never reaches the boundary?
2) What is the “exit time”, the expected time for a particle starting at $p$ to reach the boundary?
3) How does the exit time depend on $p$?

Comment: 1) is easy. There is a nonzero probability that the first $n$ steps will be in the same direction. So if the region is rectangular, there is a nonzero probability that the walk will take you to an edge in the shortest way possible. And so the probability it never reaches the boundary is $0$.

Comment: @alex.jordan Could you write me a solution for all 3 questions ?

Comment: If someone could help me in any way with questions 2 and 3, that would be much appreciated

Comment: I don't see an easy way to answer 2) and 3). I only commented on 1) because it was the only one I see as easy. If I had an answer for 2) and 3) I would probably try for the bounty.

Comment: @alex.jordan Do you have maybe a direction that I could follow or things that I coud try ?

Comment: If $e(p)$ denotes the exit time starting at $p$, then you can condition on the first step, and get that $e(p) = 1 + 1/4 \sum e(p')$ where $p'$ runs over the 4 neighbors of $p$. On the boundary you have $e(p)=0$, so you will get a system of linear equations (which really is the discrete Poisson equation $\Delta e = 1$ with zero boundary values.) I don't really know of a slick way to solve this in general.

Comment: It's generally considered bad form to (effectively) remove a question after receiving an answer; I've rolled back to the version of this question that had actual content in it.